# finding max min values in day using timestamp and adding it to existing dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a dataframe consisting of timestamp and some environmental values. I want to find  the maximum and minimum temperature values of the day and store it with the existing dataframe into a csv file.

[image: csv]

So far I was able to use the below code and bring the maximum and minimum values ina separate dataframe.

''''

```
    dff = pd.read_csv(n1p2.csv")

    df =  pd.DataFrame(dff)

    df['timeStamp'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['timeStamp'])

    df = df.set_index('timeStamp')

    val = df.loc[df.groupby(df.index.dayofyear).idxmax().iloc[:, 2]]
```

''''

The dataframe val has maximum values of SItemp for each day. But How do i add it to the original dataframe and save the csv file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'id': [1, 2, 3], 'datatime': ['16-12-19 13:23', '16-12-19 17:45', '17-12-19 13:23'], 'temp': [35,41,32]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df = df.set_index('id')
df
```

Sample Date:

```
      datatime     temp
id      
1   16-12-19 13:23  35
2   16-12-19 17:45  41
3   17-12-19 13:23  32

df['NewDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datatime'],format='%d-%m-%y %H:%M')
df['Date Only']=df['NewDate'].dt.date
df
```

Only Date:

```
      datatime     temp  NewDate    Date Only
id              
1   16-12-19 13:23  35  2019-12-16 13:23:00 2019-12-16
2   16-12-19 17:45  41  2019-12-16 17:45:00 2019-12-16
3   17-12-19 13:23  32  2019-12-17 13:23:00 2019-12-17
```

Find minimum and maximum:

```
import numpy as np
data = (df.set_index('Date Only').groupby(level=0)['temp']
          .agg([('Minimum',np.min),('Maximum',np.max)]))
data
```

Result:

```
         Minimum    Maximum
Date Only       
2019-12-16  35       41
2019-12-17  32       32
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help. This worked. I was able to put it into a different dataframe. But now I know that its not possible to put the max min values in the same dataframe since the rows will mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

I think easiest from this point is to just generate date column to original dataframe and then merge val to that one.

I have not tested but should be something like below.

```
df['date']=df.index.date
dfFull=df.merge(val, how='left' left_on='date', right_on='dayofyear')
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answers. However the original dataframe is larger compared to searching for the maximum minimum values of a day. Hence merging both of them together is practically a wrong way of doing it unless the new columns prints the max-min values corresponding to the rows of the timestamp in data frame.

Comment: Hi sorry edits added. Yes i understand. Is it ok to have max value for all corresponding rows in certain date? If you generate new date only column from timestamp then you can join to this and still have the min max values present for each day.